# ¿Cómo envio un parámetro de la ubicación de una imagen a una variable en JavaScript propia¡ de una librería?

Tags: javascript

actualmente trabajo en una aplicación web que genera códigos QR en base a texto y estoy utilizando la librería [Kjua](https://larsjung.de/kjua/)

en la documentación de Kjua acepta las siguiente opciones:

```
    var el = kjua({
text: 'hello!',
image: null

});
document.querySelector('body').appendChild(el);
```

en esta opcion `image` desearía utilizar una imagen almacenada dentro del documento, solo que no se como enviarla, si es con un `.getElementById` o almacenar la dirección como una cadena en una variable.

Kjua tiene una [demo](https://larsjung.de/kjua/latest/demo/) de la librería en acción donde utiliza un formulario para usar imágenes desde los archivos del usuario, y tiene una imagen por defecto, solo que es confuso.
de antemano gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Necesitas enviar LA imagen en si como file o necesitas la ruta?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes obtener el `src` de tu imagen asi :

```
var image = document.getElementById("image").src;
```

Answer (score 1):

Si deseas obtener la imagen yo usaría `getElementById`, debería funcionar. En cambio, si lo que necesitas es el source de la imagen, haría:

```
var img= document.getElementByTagName('img')[0];
var source = img.src;
```

Siendo el número entre corchetes el número de posición de la imagen, antes deberías declararle su contenedor y su posición para ser precisos.